# Managing access rights in GitLab group

Tags: git, gitlab, access-rights

I have a GitLab group (with `owner` rights). In the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md) I red, that only `master` (and higher access levels) can create the new repository in the group. But **all** users in the group (even with `Guest` access rights) can **read** all projects in it.

How can I allow users to transfer the repositories into the group, but disallow them to read other repositories in it? I.e., each user must have `owner` rights to its repository, but `None` rights to others in the group.

If this is impossible, I can manually create repositories for groupmembers, but **how can I make each repository readable (and editable) only for one groupmember?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create the repositories for the users, if you dont want them to see other repositories in the group.

But afterwards you can edit the `Members` of each repository (not of the group) and just add the users to every single repository like you want. These users then just see the repositories where you added them.

Group permissions are inherited by the repositories, but repository permissions stay with that repository.

Comment: Is it or is it not possible to add a user to a group's repository?

Comment: @DushyantBangal You can add users to repositories/projects and to groups and subgroups. The permission level of a user is inherited from group, to subgroup to project. So you may either set permissions on a group or on each project.